# Weird behavior of Rxjs map operator while catching error

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, resolver

I wanted to fetch data by `http` request using `Resolver` while my backend server wasn't running. I was switching between couple of my pages which I created to check if everything works as It should. Almost everything was fine but not one of my pages. It was not allowing me to navigate to this page by throwing error: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse`. However, I was using in every other page `Resolver` to fetch data like on this page. There was only one difference: in working case - I was calling helper method from other class in `.map()` which was giving me generic object with `error` and `body`, in non working case - I was doing the same what was doing this helper method but inside of `.map()` I had "coppied" the code of this method.

Not working example:

```
   .pipe(
  map((value: ProcessDefinitionSearchResponse) => {
      const httpResponseResolved: HttpResponseResolved<ProcessDefinitionSearchResponse> = {
        body: value,
        error: null
      };
      return httpResponseResolved;
    },
    catchError(error => of(asHttpErrorResponse(error))))
);
```

Working example:

```
    .pipe(
  map(processParameters => asHttpSuccessResponse(processParameters)),
  catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => of(asHttpErrorResponse(err)))
);
```

Method codes:

```
  export function asHttpErrorResponse(error: HttpErrorResponse): HttpResponseResolved<any> {
    return {
      error,
      body: null
    };
  }
```

Why is that?

Comment: In your not-working example you are missing a closing parenthesis after the body of the mapping function. Is that a typo?

Comment: If that is not a typo, then catchError would be passed as second argument to the map function (as `thisArg`) which would explain your error.

Comment: You are right, It was passed as second `map` argument. That's why It wasn't working.  Thanks a lot.